# Image processing using C# for currency detection

Tags: c#, image-processing, image-preprocessing

Is there any reference for the currency detection using image processing in c# ?
For example I will feed the picture of the currency note to the code and it detects the currency ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic (point 4.)

Comment: I would also suggest investigating whether having images of currency is legal, which is also off topic for this site. For example https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/banknotes/using-images-of-banknotes